# Conflicting typescript global definition

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a project with the following definition extending express request type:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      // ... a bunch of other properties
      ctx: AppContext:
    }
  }
}
```

In this project i'm importing a library, that has another dependency that re-declares the request type:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      ctx: LibraryContext:
    }
  }
}
```

When I import the library, the compiler imports the transitive dependency types too and the types in my project get messed up.

I've tried setting up an overrides folder like this:

```
project
│
├── overrides
│   ├── @library-scope
│   │_____library
│   │     │__ index.d.ts
│   │     │__ types.d.ts   <--- this is where the global is added in the library
│   │
└── tsconfig.json
```

and adding overrides to typeroots in tsconfig:

```json
"typeRoots": [
  "overrides",
  "node_modules/@types",
]
```

but looking at the tsc log with trace resolutions enabled it still picks up the type from node_modules. I tried different variations of options, flat directory structure in overrides with `library-scope__library` directory and defintions inside, but nothing seems to help.

Is there any way to prevent the library type from being merged with the project type?